# Graphing crime rates on stata

Tags: graph, stata

I am new to stata. I am trying to write code in stata that would graph Idaho's crime rate from 2016 - 2021. I'm using data from the FBI: (https://cde.ucr.cjis.gov/LATEST/webapp/#/pages/downloads#nibrs-downloads). Wondering if anyone had any tips?

Answer (score 0):

can you give more detail about how the original data illustrate the crime rate?
if you have the year and corresponding crime rate

you can try

```
twoway (line rate year)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a bit more information might be helpful but based upon what you sent, I think this might be of use. It looks like you would need to use the "NIBRS_incident.csv" file for years 2016-2021. After downloading these files, you would need to append these files to create a workfile with all 6 years of data. Once you've done that, you can create a count variable by year with:

```
by data_year: gen Incidence_By_Yr = _N
```

Then, following the comment above with the twoway graph.

```
twoway(line Incidence_By_Yr year)
```